# How to do physical QSL when not operating from your home QTH?

Tags: qsl-card, etiquette

If you have preprinted QSL cards that have your home address and grid square on them, what's considered the most proper way to do a physical QSL exchange for a contact that was made while you were operating away from home?

Do you cross out the location info on the QSL card and write in where you actually were?  Do you put your operating location on the comment line and hope they notice that and don't bounce your QSL for "not in log"?  Do you leave a comment and attach a note to make it really clear you weren't operating from home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would use /P after your callsign when you made the contact, or some other indication that you were away from home (in the US, it's not uncommon to say the call district you're operating from - W1AW/6 for a station temporarily operating in California).

I would skip the preprinted QSL card and print a new one on cardstock with an inkjet, but that's just me. You could write all the information on a blank index card and that would be valid for QSL purposes. Adding "operating portable from..." to the address would be helpful.